# VSCode Prettier not formatting schema.json

Tags: reactjs, prettier

Prettier is not formatting schema.json in my react app.
This is the error that prettier gives in the output of VSCode:

```
["ERROR" - 2:16:28 PM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 2:16:28 PM] Unexpected token, expected "," (1867:281)
  1865 |   kind: "SCALAR",
  1866 |   name: "ID",
> 1867 |   description: "The `ID` scalar type represents a unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as key for a cache. The ID type appears in a JSON response as a String; however, it is not intended to be human-readable. When expected as an input type, any string (such as `"4"`) or integer (such as `4`) input value will be accepted as an ID.",
```

Comment: The issue was with JSON View extension on google chrome. It skipped "" from each line key. Disabled it and its perfectly working now.